# Cake php 2.X project is working on localhost but not on live server after adding Auth Component

Tags: authentication, cakephp, controller, components

In my project everything was working fine and when i added Auth component it ran perfectly on localhost but giving error index() not found.I have tried everything and finally gave up.What might be a problem .. It is a mod rewrite thing or i am making a mistake in something else .Do i need to do additional settings before adding my app to live servers.

I will really appreciate any help.

*My header and footer are loading correctly from layout but the different views i am trying to call are not working it happened after adding auth component thats the only significant change i did to the project.*

Error as follows:-
    Missing View

```
Error: The view for HomesController::index() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: /hermes/bosoraweb180/b2111/sl.appatronicscom/public_html/appatronics/app/View/homes/index.>ctp

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create >app/View/Errors/missing_view.ctp

Stack Trace

CORE/Cake/View/View.php line 468 → View->_getViewFileName(null)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 948 → View->render(null, null)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 194 → Controller->render()
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(HomesController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 109 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Comment: Hi can you check you have proper permission on view.. just comment you auth component and try it...

Comment: Yes i checked that and i got the solution the reason i was getting that  because i was not following the name conventions of my controller class.I was using $name='homes'  but in my views I had Homes folder.That was the whole issue.And now its working like charm.How ever its strange that it worked okay on localhost but gave me error view not found.My server is linux server.